# to display whether a specific number is in array -matlab

Tags: matlab

the program is

```
clc;
clear;
d =input('enter the hop count of all path');  % [ 1 2 3]
en=[1 0 0 0 0 0 0;   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ;   1 1 0 0 0 0 0; 1 0 1 0 1 0 1; 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
c = cumsum(d);    % [1, 3, 6]
s = ceil(size(en,1)*c/c(end));    % [2, 5, 9] 
n = [s(1) diff(s)]; % [2, 3, 4]
B = mat2cell(en, n, size(en,2)); 
n=1;
for i=1:length(d)

disp(sprintf('the transmiting frame thr path %d ',n));
disp(B{i});
n=n+1;
end
disp ('SINGLE BIT ERROR');
        S=randint(1,1,[1,size(en,1)]);
        T=randint(1,1,[1,size(en,2)]);
        if (en(S,T)==1)
            en(S,T)=0;
        elseif (en(S,T)==0)
            en(S,T)=1;
        end
        disp(en);
        disp('SINGLE BIT ERROR INTRODUCED AT');
        disp(S);               %row
        disp(T);                % column
        p=S*T; 
        disp('error at bit');
        disp(p);                       %displays which bit is error

for i=1:length(d)
    disp(sprintf('size of transmitted frame %d',i));
    disp(size(B{i}));              % size of each transmitted frame
    ee(i)=(size(B{i},1)*size(B{i},2)); 
end
disp('display (row*column) of each frame');
    disp(ee(:));               % displays (row*column) of each frame
kk=cumsum(ee(:));
disp('the cumulative sumation is ');
disp(kk);                    % cumulative sumation of the elements in ee
```

the output will be

```
enter the hop count of all path[ 1 2 3]

en =

     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     1     0     1     0     1
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0

the transmiting frame thr path 1 
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0

the transmiting frame thr path 2 
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     0     0     0     0     0

the transmiting frame thr path 3 
     1     0     1     0     1     0     1
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0

SINGLE BIT ERROR
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     1     0     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0

SINGLE BIT ERROR INTRODUCED AT
     4

     6

error at bit
    24

size of transmitted frame 1
     1     7

size of transmitted frame 2
     2     7

size of transmitted frame 3
     2     7

 display (row*column) of each frame
     7
    14
    14

the cumulative sumation is 
     7
    21
    35

>>
```

Hence p=24 which exist between kk(2) and kk(3). It should display saying 'frame 3 has  error'. Likewise if p<=kk(1),it should display' frame 1 has error' and if p is between kk(1) and kk(2), it should display 'frame 2 has error'. But length (d) varies accordingly with input of user. Am not able to display it like this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SPRINTF function. Since `kk` is output of `cumsum` function, it's sorted, and you can use `find` to find the frame index.

```
if p <= kk(end)
    idx = find((kk-p)>=0, 1);
    disp( sprintf('frame %d has error',idx) )
end
```